# Достать весь текст что внутри {} python

Tags: python, python-3.x

у меня есть файл `main.txt`

внутри на допустим 8 строке есть

```
создать тест (траст){

    печатать(1)

    печатать(2)

    печатать(3)
}

создать тест2 (траст){

    печать(4)

    печать(5)

    печать(6)
}
```

у меня есть номер строки , где {, как узнать на какой строке }?

Так вот вопрос, как мне достать всё строки что идут между {}?

Comment: Форматирование правильное? Есть ли ещё знаки `{`,`}` в файле?

Comment: Есть , но не на этих строчках.

Comment: Приведите более точное описание формата файла тогда, пока непонятно как регулярками найти

Comment: Используйте [кнопку править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1143554/edit)

Answer (score 0):

https://repl.it/repls/EquatorialBurlyStartup

```
import re

with open('main.txt', 'r') as file:
  data = file.read()

  print(data)

  print(re.findall('\{([\s\S]*?)\}', data))
```